# two different app logins on single Firebase project Problem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Problem in the login. Basically, I tell you my scenario.
I have two apps both are connected with a single firebase project. 
One app contains driver login and other app contain customer login
When I open a customer app and register the new customer. The customer is successfully registered. And then I open the driver app and entered the customer credential means (Customer email & password) its login successfully and open the driver activity and vice-versa.

how to fix this issue I am using firebase.

customer login activity

```
    public class CustomerLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
    private Button mLogin, mRegistration;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(user!=null ){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerLoginActivity.this, CustomerMapActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegistration = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registration);

        mRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers").child(user_id);
                            current_user_db.setValue(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(CustomerLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(CustomerLoginActivity.this, "sign in error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }
}
```

driver login activity

```
    public class DriverLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
    private Button mLogin, mRegistration;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(user!=null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DriverLoginActivity.this, DriverMapActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegistration = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registration);

        mRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(DriverLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(DriverLoginActivity.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(user_id).child("name");
                            current_user_db.setValue(email);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(DriverLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(DriverLoginActivity.this, "sign in error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }
}
```

[My database rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AJkl.jpg)

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: when i  open driver app and entered the customer email and password it logged in without giving me error ....

Comment: when I open customer app and entered driver email and password it logged in without giving me an error...which means driver becomes customer and customer becomes driver.....which i don't want....please help me out

Comment: How I can make a difference between customer and driver means when I open driver app the only driver can be login and when I open customer app the only customer can be login......currently no matter which app is opened if you entered the customer data you will be the customer if you entered the driver data you will be driver so this my actual problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase authentication doesn't differentiate between different "types" of users, like you're trying to do. You'll have to implement some custom logic of your own in your app(s) to handle these situations. The base `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method will always work if you provide it correct credentials... so what you need to do is in your app code, BEFORE you call the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method, check to see if the provided username is "allowed" to use this version of the app...

So as soon as you get their username, before calling that signIn method, make a query to the database to determine whether that username belongs to a "customer" or a "driver". I assume you have something like a `/users` node in your database - if you don't, you'll need to create one, there's no way around it. If you're not sure how to query the database, use the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method... check out the [official docs for examples/syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once).

Once you've determined whether the username is for a customer vs a driver... you will need to implement logic to decide whether they are allowed to proceed to the signIn method.

- If they are a "customer" and this is the "customer" app, then allow the code to proceed to the signIn method... but if the username comes back as a "driver" then stop the code and display an error to the user.
- Similarly for the "driver" app, if the username comes back as being for a "driver" then allow the code to proceed to the signIn method... but if it comes back as a "customer" then stop the code and display an error to the user.

Comment: Thanks, It really helpful I make a query that checks the email. before sign in...

Comment: @WasifCjz Awesome, glad it was useful! If my answer was helpful, please click the outlined checkmark to the left of the answer. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question will be marked as "having an accepted answer". It helps anyone searching for similar topics in the future, and gives me credit for the effort I put in. :) Thanks!

Comment: Shoutout to @JeremyW